# Load an ini file in Project/app in Android?

Tags: java, android, ini

I have a file in Project/app/apiconfig.ini
[like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUsg3.png)
inside file:

```
api_key = API_KEY
```

I create class to read the ini file and get the values:

```
package br.com.adley.myseriesproject.library;

import org.ini4j.Ini;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Adley on 15/04/2016.
 * Read a ini config file
 */
public class ReadIniConfigFile {
    private String configurationFile;
    private final String defaultConfigPath = "apiconfig.ini";
    private HashMap<String, String> iniFile;

    public HashMap<String, String> getIniFile() {
        return iniFile;
    }

    public void setIniFile(HashMap<String, String> iniFile) {
        this.iniFile = iniFile;
    }

    public ReadIniConfigFile(String iniConfFilePath, String... keys) {
        configurationFile = iniConfFilePath == null ? defaultConfigPath : iniConfFilePath;
        Ini ini = loadIni();
        if(ini != null){
            if(keys.length > 0){
                for (String key:keys) {
                    iniFile.put(key,ini.get(key).toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ReadIniConfigFile(String iniConfFilePath, String key) {
        configurationFile = iniConfFilePath == null ? defaultConfigPath : iniConfFilePath;
        Ini ini = loadIni();
        if(ini != null){
            iniFile.put(key,ini.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
    public ReadIniConfigFile(String... keys) {
        configurationFile =  defaultConfigPath;
        Ini ini = loadIni();
        if(ini != null){
            if(keys.length > 0){
                for (String key:keys) {
                    iniFile.put(key,ini.get(key).toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ReadIniConfigFile(String key) {
        configurationFile =  defaultConfigPath;
        Ini ini = loadIni();
        if(ini != null){
            iniFile.put(key,ini.get(key).toString());
        }
    }

    public Ini loadIni() {
        try{
            Ini ini = new Ini(new File(configurationFile));
            return ini;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String,String> getAllIni() {
        return iniFile;
    }

    public String getSpecificValueIni(String key){
        return iniFile.get(key);
    }

    public Collection<String> getAllValues(){
        return iniFile.values();
    }

    public String getSpecificKeyValueIniToString(String key){
        return key + " = " + iniFile.get(key);
    }

}
```

My question is, how can I get the path to this ini file?
Have another way to save an api_key outside code? Cause i'm using GitHub and don't want to share my private key.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Path class, you can get the real path to your file on your file system. Customize the code below to your liking:

```
Path path = Paths.get("loremipsum.txt").toRealPath(LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

see the docs about the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class.

Since you already have a class to ready an external file to get your api key, just put that file path in your `.gitignore` file and it won't be commited and/or pushed to github.

Comment: I've tried, but the Paths.get has no reference, I mean, Path path; works fine, but when I try to use Paths.get the Android Studio say "Cannot resolve symbol 'Paths'. Then I've searched to import some class, but didn't find anyone

Comment: `Paths` is a java 7 class, what version of Java is your project set to?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_74 in project and to compile project: compileSdkVersion 23